# Run time Error 13

Tags: excel, runtime-error, vba

```
Option Explicit

Sub value()

    Dim mynumber As Integer, mysum As Integer, myextra As Integer
    mynumber = Range("A2:A17")
    myextra = Range("B2:B17")
    mysum = mynumber * myextra
    MsgBox ("mysum")

End Sub
```

Why do I get `Run time Error 13`?

Comment: What are you expecting your result to be? Can you give us an example of numbers that would be in columns A and B and what the expected result would be? There are a number of different things we could suggest, but need more information. i.e. are you multiplying the sum of the columns, or is it a2*b2 + a3*b3, or something else?

Answer (score 0):

This error means there is a type mismatch.

Make sure the ranges actually contain integers.

`mynumber` and `myextra` should be declared as arrays by following their names with parentheses:

```
Dim mynumber() As Integer, mysum As Integer, myextra() As Integer
```